# Set an email reminders meeting in the Outlook application, to a different email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to set reminders in the Outlook application for Windows, such that an hour before every meeting, an email will be sent **to a different address**, with the meeting details.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, I am afraid that your needs could not be achieved with the functions of the Outlook client alone.